# Unable to deploy project to Scrapy Cloud

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, scrapinghub

I made changes to the spider to use some methods of the scrapinghub API and tried re-deploying it to Scrapy Cloud using "shub deploy".
I'm getting an error:
ImportError: No module named scrapinghub

It points to the import line in the spider

```
from scrapinghub import Connection
```

shub version 2.5.0
scrapinghub (1.9.0)

I'm able to run spider locally.

Any ideas what is the problem ?

Comment: are you using any kind of virtual environment?

Comment: yes i'm  usingvirtualenv

Comment: check that `shub` is inside your environment, check the path when using `which shub` in terminal

Comment: shub  and scrapinghub are inside my environment. I'm able to run spider locally using current virtual environment.

Comment: try `shub deploy-reqs` if you have a `requirements.txt` file ready.

Comment: Adding requirements.txt helped, but I got a warning from scrapycloud regarding deploying in such way. So I added the requirements.txt but deployed using standard shub deploy command - so it worked. Actually strange since according to docs  scrapinghub is part of the hworker stack. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Adding requirements.txt with

```
# Scrapinghub
scrapinghub==1.9.0
```

and updating the scrapinghub.yml solved the issue.
Thanks to [Carlos Peña](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1806963/carlos-pe%C3%B1a)